# RPI3 Stuck in SSH on boot

Tags: boot, ssh

I can not open the graphical interface,
I have used `startx` I get a bunch of paragraphs pop up and that is the furthest I can get.

When I start up the raspberry pi 3, It says the bluetooth thing is failed and 2 other's about connecting to x server.It asks for my login and password which I enter  `pi` and `my chosen password` then I get into the ssh. If I run startx I get paragraphs come up. I tried typing in `leafpad` but it says it unable to open the graphical interface. I can use `python` and it opens idle in ssh. I can't do `rm xxx` it says It is a read only file system.

Have I got an corrupted sd card?

Comment: Hello. Could you copy-and-paste the "bunch of paragraphs" you get when you run `startx` into your question? The Bluetooth and X-Server errors might be handy as well. This will help us answer your question as we can't see your screen from here.

Comment: From your rather vague question, you appear to be trying to run the GUI over `ssh` - this is not possible; try VNC

Comment: Milliways How? And Roget Jones I really can't since I can't even access the internet on the raspberry pi

Comment: Is it stuck in ssh (are you sure you understand what ssh is? Google it.) or is it stuck in the console/shell?

Comment: Mark, I can't load anything graphical